# Skip by Id on large list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc

This is in ASP.NET MVC, but that shouldn't make a difference. I have a large number of rows in my database for `Songs`.

```
var songIndex = Context.Songs.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.Id == 500);
var songs = Context.Songs.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(songIndex).Take(10);
```

However, the `ToList()` and `OrderBy` seem pretty heavy just to take the next next 10 songs after the element with Id of 500.

Is there a better way to do this so I don't have to modify the entire list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a simple `Where` clause?

```
var songs = Context.Songs
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Where(x => x.Id > 500)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't think of this, it put me on the right track.

I modified it to this as it will be more efficient I imagine: `Context.Songs.Where(x => x.Id > 500 && x => x.Id <= (id + 10))` rather than getting all past 500 and only taking 10 (correct me if I am wrong).